# Odoo (OpenERP) start-stop-daemon script

Tags: 14.04, bash, scripts, services, odoo

I installed odoo and try manual start openerp-server. All ok. My next step it's try to add odoo to auto start. For this I use this script:

```
#!/bin/sh

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:             openerp-server
# Required-Start:       $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:        $remote_fs $syslog
# Should-Start:         $network
# Should-Stop:          $network
# Default-Start:        2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:         0 1 6
# Short-Description:    Enterprise Resource Management software
# Description:          Open ERP is a complete ERP and CRM software.
### END INIT INFO

PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin
DAEMON=/opt/odoo/openerp-server
NAME=openerp-server
DESC=openerp-server

# Specify the user name (Default: openerp).
USER=root

# Specify an alternate config file (Default: /etc/openerp-server.conf).
CONFIGFILE="/etc/openerp-server.conf"

# pidfile
PIDFILE=/var/run/$NAME.pid

# Additional options that are passed to the Daemon.
DAEMON_OPTS="-c $CONFIGFILE"

[ -x $DAEMON ] || exit 0
[ -f $CONFIGFILE ] || exit 0

checkpid() {
    [ -f $PIDFILE ] || return 1
    pid=`cat $PIDFILE`
    [ -d /proc/$pid ] && return 0
    pid=`cat $PIDFILE`
    [ -d /proc/$pid ] && return 0
    return 1
}

case "${1}" in
        start)
                echo -n "Starting ${DESC}: "

                start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile ${PIDFILE} \
                        --chuid ${USER} --background --make-pidfile \
                        --exec ${DAEMON} -- ${DAEMON_OPTS}

                echo "${NAME}."
                ;;

        stop)
                echo -n "Stopping ${DESC}: "

                start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --pidfile ${PIDFILE} \
                        --oknodo

                echo "${NAME}."
                ;;

        restart|force-reload)
                echo -n "Restarting ${DESC}: "

                start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --pidfile ${PIDFILE} \
                        --oknodo

                sleep 1

                start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile ${PIDFILE} \
                        --chuid ${USER} --background --make-pidfile \
                        --exec ${DAEMON} -- ${DAEMON_OPTS}

                echo "${NAME}."

                echo "${NAME}."
                ;;

        *)
                N=/etc/init.d/${NAME}
                echo "Usage: ${NAME} {start|stop|restart|force-reload}" >&2
               exit 1
               ;;
esac

exit 0
```

When I start script, pid file created but service don't work. Also if I try to stop it, I see msg:

```
Stopping openerp-server: start-stop-daemon: warning: failed to kill 1204: No such process openerp-server.
```

I don't understand what I do wrong. And my old friend google can't help me.
[this don't help](https://www.odoo.com/fr_FR/forum/help-1/question/warning-failed-to-kill-30449-no-such-process-23158)

Maybe anybody have solve for this problem?

Comment: The start-stop-daemon itself may have something to log. Edit your script and add something like `>> /var/log/odoo.log` after every `start-stop-daemon` command. Start and stop your process, and see if something shows up in the log.

Comment: I try --logfile ${LFILE} (don't work) and >> ${LFILE} (log is empty)
To log file I give chmod 777, and it's don't help

Comment: What if you issue the `start-stop-daemon` command yourself?

Comment: if I try to stop it, I see msg:

Stopping openerp-server: start-stop-daemon: warning: failed to kill 1204: No such process openerp-server.

Comment: Can you get the server running with `sudo /opt/odoo/openerp-server -c /etc/openerp-server.conf &`? Because that is basically all the `start-stop-daemon` command does when you start the service.

Comment: yea, i can manual start, and all be ok if I do it. process created and log writing. if I need stop him, I use kill command. But if I start from sh (example: sudo su root; sh /etc/init.d/odoo-test start) pid file is creating, but odoo don't work, and i can't stop from sh /etc/init.d/odoo-test stop

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to run openerp as root thats why it fails, change:

```
# Specify the user name (Default: openerp).
USER=root
```

by

```
# Specify the user name (Default: openerp).
USER=YOUR_USER_THAT_RUNS_ODOO
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. I fixed it by adding the odoo-server init.d script in the system starting menu.
Create a link with the following command :

```
$ sudo update-rc.d odoo-server defaults
```